# How to delete extra spaces in an input type="text"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this input type="text" and this button which shows the users input, but if the input have extra spaces, them will be showed too.How to remove these extra spaces form the input value?

```js
var nameInput = $('#name');

function showName() {
    if (nameInput.val() === "") {
      alert('You must provide a Name');
    }
    else {
      alert('¡Hello' + ' ' + nameInput.val() + '!')
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button type="button" onclick="showName()"> Show Name </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.trim()` to remove extra spaces to remove trailing and preceding spaces.

To remove any multiple occurrence of space then use `.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();`

```
var _name = nameInput.val().trim();
if (_name === "") {
  alert('You must provide a Name');
}
else {
  alert('¡Hello' + ' ' + _name + '!')
}
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?

Answer (score -1):

You can call trim(), as in `nameInput.val().trim()`

Edit: Odd that i was downvoted 1 second after posting the answer. Somebody is spiteful